# Is it possible to set up middleware for props using styled components

Tags: css, jsx, styled-components, middleware

I'm playing around with styled components and I've hit a problem. I would like to create a prop that does the same thing to any styled component I pass it to.

For example:

```
<StyledDiv bg="blue"/>
```

This prop should always be interpreted as `background-color: blue` in any styled component it's passed to, without manually doing this:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  ${({bg}) => `background-color: ${bg}`}
`
```

For every single component. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, but it's not great in my opinion. I couldn't find any kind of middleware solution with styled components, so I just made a wrapper function that takes a styled component as an argument.

The wrapper function returns a new component that modifies the props before passing them to the styled component. Here's the implementation:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const _globalProps = {
  sm: props => `
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      ${props}
    }
  `,
}

const _styleWrapper = (StyledComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    // bypass immutable react props object
    props = {...props};

    // access styled component style body
    const styleRules = StyledComponent.componentStyle.rules;

    // if the prop you passed is in _globalProps, add the global style to the style body
    for (const prop in props) {
      const gProp = _globalProps[prop];
      if (gProp) styleRules[styleRules.length] = gProp(props[prop]);
    }

    // return the styled component with the modified style body
    return (
      <StyledComponent {...props}>
        {props.children}
      </StyledComponent>
    );
  };
};

const Container = _styleWrapper(styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.backgroundColor};
`);

export default Container;
```

Now for any styled component wrapped inside `_styleWrapper`, you can pass a prop called `sm` which will add a media query with specified fields to that component.

Example:

```
import Container from './components/styled/Container';

function App() {
  return (
    <Container sm="margin: 0" backgroundColor="red">
      ...
    </Container>
  );
}
```

When the screen width dips below `700px`, the container will now lose it's margin.